Gradle build error caused by kapt and room
I got this error after opening Android Studio, it worked before.
I'm trying to use room to store infos in my app and when I remove dependencies for room and kapt it works again

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.PropertyEvaluationException: Error while evaluating property 'ifKaptClasspathIsPresent' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

This is my build.gradle
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.st"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.st"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    //nav
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")

    //scaffold
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.2")

    //custom shape
    implementation("androidx.graphics:graphics-shapes:1.0.0-alpha05")

    //retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0")

    //coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0")


    //viewmodel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0")


    //Room
    val room_version = "2.6.1"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")


}

If I remove implement and annotation and kapt it works again.
I tried using ksp instead of kapt but I still get errors.

am I seeing it correctly you're using annotationProcessor alongside kapt? if you want to use kapt or ksp remove the annotationProcessor
